# Why do we have to use "Convert" with integers, but not with strings?

Tags: c#, .net

This isn't a "I got a problem question". This is a generic question that I got.

So, I am programming a sudoku because I am bored and I got a question.

```
label1.text = int1.toString();
```

Why does this work but not this:

```
int1 = label1.text.ToInt32();
```

Why exactly do we have to use Convert function? Like this:

```
int1 = Convert.ToInt32(label1.text);
```

Comment: We don't have to use `Convert`. There's no `ToInt32()`. We do need to parse text if we want to get the numeric or date values, with the appropriate `Parse` methods like `int.Parse()`, `DateTime.Parse` etc

Comment: There are trade offs. In designing the framework, they decided that converting "anything" to a string would be a universal desire (think about debuggers, etc that have to show you the current value of something, and in the early days there weren't additional debug hooks). Whereas conversion to `Int32` is far less "universal" - only really making sense from a few types.

Comment: Besides, there's an infinite number of types. It's impossible to create a `String.ToXYZ` method for all of them. It's the *type's* job to provide its own `ToString()` and `Parse` implementations

Comment: If you really want, you *could* create your own `.ToInt32()` [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (where you would then call Convert or Parse)

Comment: Short: **every** object can sure provide some string-representation of itself. However not everything can be **numerically** expressed, or what number would you expect `myTree` to become? Surely you *could* add semantics to a number to express some `Tree`, but why would you ever want that?

Answer (score -1):

The "ToString" initial goal is not to convert the object into string.
The goal is to be the "abstraction function".

> An abstraction function that maps rep values to the abstract values
> they represent

More about the [abstraction function](http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa14/classes/09-af-ri-equality/)

It means it will be used to have an idea of the current state of the object and it's easier to have it as a string.

So ToString is not a "convert to string" function, it is a "give me the abstraction of this object" and the result is a string.

Example :

Let's say I will implement my own date.
The abstraction will be a date containing a year, a month and a day (from the external world it will be like that) but internally I can manage that differently :

- I can have 3 fields (year/month/day).
- I can have the Unix Epoch (number of ms since 1970)
- ...

The ToString will convert the representation (3 fields or Unix Epoch, ...) to the abstraction expected from the external world.

Comment: This is wrong. `ToString` is not supposed to be an abstraction to an exact representation, that is a serialization mechanism. [Quote from docs: "It converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for display."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0) For example, `new List<int>{1,2}.ToString()` returns `"System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.Int32]"` not `"1,2"`

Comment: Making something "suitable for display" is not so different from the purpose of the abstraction function so why is it wrong? I don't see in the documentation you linked it's a serialization mechanism. If it was the case the example you show for List<int> prove is not a good serialization mechanism.

Comment: I agree the default ToString mechanism (displaying the type) is not an abstraction function (it's obviously not possible to write an abstraction function that will suit every newly created types) but it has been overriden in a few cases (Datetime, Timespan, int, ...) and in those cases the ToString is an abstraction function. It's not because it has not been implemented everywhere my statement is wrong. And according to the doc you linked I still convinced the purpose of ToString is to be a kind of abstraction function.